# How to get the selected value from drop down list and submit it to my Details view?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an mvc razor form. What i want is to submit the user's selection from Items dropdown list and navigate to Details view in order to access the chosen item's information.

Currently when i click the submit button i navigate succesfully to Details view but there is absolutely no data showing there.

The selected value has to be from the Items drop down list that i build using the jquery in my view...

As you can see i tried to use the "ItemsID" but all i get is null when checking with the brakepoint my details view.

Can you please help me?

**View:**

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("Details", "Bookings", FormMethod.Post))
{
<fieldset>
    <legend> Type/Item</legend>
    <label for="Items">Item Types </label>
    @Html.DropDownList("department", ViewBag.ItemTypesList as SelectList, "Select a Type", new { id = "ItemTypeID" })
    <div id="ItemsDivId">
        <label for="Items">Items </label>
        <select id="ItemsID" name="Items"></select>
    </div>
    <p>
        <input type ="submit" value="Submit" id="SubmitID" />
    </p>
 </fieldset>
}


    <script type="text/javascript">

        $('#ItemTypeID').on('change', function () {
            $.ajax({
                type: 'POST',
                url: '@Url.Action("GetItemTypeForm")',
            data: { itemTypeId: $('#ItemTypeID').val() },
            success: function (results) {
                var options = $('#ItemsID');
                options.empty();
                options.append($('<option />').val(null).text("- Select an Item -"));
                $.each(results, function () {
                    options.append($('<option />').val(this.ItemsID).text(this.Value));
                });
            }
        });
    });
</script>
```

**Controller:**

```
public ActionResult Details(string ItemsID)
        {
            var item = db.Items.Find(ItemsID);

            return View(item);
        }

[HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetItemTypeForm(string itemTypeId)
        {
            //pseudo code
            var data = from s in db.Items
                       where s.ItemType.ItemTypeName == itemTypeId
                       select new { Value = s.ItemName, ItemsID = s.ItemId };


            return Json(data);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you everyone for looking,

The correct answer was to use "Items"